# How do I divide doubles correctly?

Tags: swift, double

My basic maths tells me: `4.0/10.0 == 0.4`

But in swift, I get:

```
4.0/10.0
> Double = 0.40000000000000002
```

What is the cause of this weirdness? How do I get the number I expected?

Comment: It's because of the imprecision of Double values. The same applies to Float.

Comment: Have a look at [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) – that applies to all binary floating point arithmetic.

Comment: And of course: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: let num1:Double = 4.0
let num2:Double = 10.0

var num3 = num1/num2
print(num3)

Comment: If you have a problem that you think can be solved with floating point arithmetic, you just risk creating 2.00000000000832 problems.